# Calling a global variable in a function in one program from another

Tags: python

I'm sure this is very simple, but I am trying to manipulate a global variable I have created in function from another script calling that function as follows:

**Script 1:**

```
def function_1():

   global myvar
   myvar = 1
```

**Script 2:**

```
from script1 import function_1

function_1()

myvar2 = myvar + 1
print myvar2
```

I don't know why that isn't working. I haven't been able to locate the exact answer I need on Stack Overflow or elsewhere. Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: You aren't actually calling the `function_1()` and you need to initialize `myvar` before calling it.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. the not calling function_1 was a typo, which i have now amended. could you please explain what you mean by not initialising myvar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables affect only the module in which they are defined.  To access it, you need to get the module object:

```
#Script2

import script1

script1.function_1()
myvar2 = script1.myvar + 1
```